# Were the clips played throughout Pawn Sacrifice actual footage?

Tags: pawn-sacrifice

I recently watched the movie *Pawn Sacrifice* and noticed that throughout the movie they would cut the scene to play "vintage" looking clips of Bobby Fischer playing Chess.

One example occurs shortly after Fischer quit from the World Championship due to perceived cheating by the Russians. Roughly half way through his speech, the scene cuts to what appears to be "real" footage of him speaking.

**Were these clips actual footage of Bobby Fischer or were they created in an attempt to add credibility/style to the movie?**

Answer (score 2):

I believe the clips were added to add credibility and style. They all showed Tobey Maguire, the actor portraying Bobby Fischer, not Fischer himself (apart from when the scenes showing Fischer as a child, when it was obviously not Maguire).

[History v Hollywood](http://www.historyvshollywood.com/reelfaces/pawn-sacrifice/) has a study comparing the film with the even more fascinating real life of Fischer. They have some good pictures showing the difference between Maguire and Fischer:

[image]

[image]

[image]

That doesn't mean to say that the footage showing news broadcasters introducing stories on Fischer aren't real (I haven't found any evidence yet to confirm if they are or are not), but the clips of Fischer himself all appear to show Maguire.